# swift: weak cannot be applied to an outlet

Tags: ios, swift, weak-references, iboutlet, zbar-sdk

I am using **libzBar** for scanning QRCode in *swift* but I am getting these errors.

[image: errors image].

First error is about weak referencing and second is undeclared type. 
At first I thought I haven't included the **ZBarReaderView.h**  but after checking the file Inspector I found that the files are correctly added as

[image: file inspector image]

I have already added a `ZBarReaderView` in Objective-C and it works fine. I have also viewed the sample project for adding an `EmbeddedReader`(ObjectiveC).

So I want to know why I am getting this error and how to remove this error?

**Solution:**

> To import a set of Objective-C files in the same app target as your
>   Swift code, you rely on an Objective-C bridging header to expose those
>   files to Swift. Xcode offers to create this header file when you add a
>   Swift file to an existing Objective-C app, or an Objective-C file to
>   an existing Swift app.

Comment: Did you import `ZBarReaderView.h` in the bridging header?

Comment: Ahh the bridging header!!. That reminds me of my first few weeks in iOS development.
 @SalavatKhanov that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you didn't create a bridging header. Follow the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) to create one and then import ZBarReaderView.h in the bridging header.